# LinkButton is not firing postback event

Tags: asp.net, postback, linkbutton, autopostback, asplinkbutton

In a web page i am using jquery and some other .js files.

The LinkButton is not firing its postback event.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"   onclick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

i am stuck in creating poskback of LinkButton control.

Any idea, how to force linkbutton to do postback.

Comment: How are you testing? Also, it should be "OnClick"

Answer (score -1):

LinkButton does not have an onclick event, [try Click instead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.click.aspx). **UPDATE** But in markup we have to use OnClick.

I don't know what are you try to achieve but LinkButton has a property called [PostBackUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.postbackurl.aspx) which can be also helpful.

**Update**

What happens if you turn off validating with [CausesValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.causesvalidation.aspx) setting to false?

Comment: I try this but the result is same.

Comment: infact the problem in one specific master page. if i create a simple page and insert a LinkButton its works fine. but not in child page (having master page).

Comment: correct me if i am wrong.By clicking LinkButton it should do postback and Page_Load must be execute.